# How to update latitude/longitude of the center of a Mapview whenever map is moved

Tags: android, android-mapview, latitude-longitude

What is the best way to constantly update the center of a mapView's latitude and longitude in an Android application?

I need to display it on a label that is shown on top of the map.  I know you can call `MapViewObject.getMapCenter()` to get a GeoPoint of the center of the map, but where would I place that code so that it is called every time the user moves the map or zooms in/out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually answered the question on my own by adding the call to `getMapCenter` in the draw method of an overlay.

```
 public MyOverlay(TextView lblCoords) {
        super();
        coordinateLabel = lblCoords;
    }

    @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            currentCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
            latitude = currentCenter.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            longitude = currentCenter.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            coordinateLabel.setText("lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude);
    }
```

You can also extend the `MapView` class and put the coordinate code in the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method so it is updated only when the user moves the screen.  This would be more efficient than putting it in an overlays onDraw, because onDraw is called constantly.

Comment: I eventually added a counter to this method so it wasn't being called on every call to draw.  Every 10 to 20 calls should be sufficient for most applications.